# Marshal java classes annotated with JAXB by StAX

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, stax

Is it possible to marshal java classes (annotated with JAXB annotations) by StAX without using  JAXB itself?

Comment: Why do you think you need this, if I may ask?

Comment: StAX is much faster than JAXB, that's the main reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, to marshall with JAXB annotations, you need JAXB - that's what it does.
**Yes**, you can use StAX as the output writer when you serialize a JAXB object tree using a Marshaller.

They are two separate things. StAX is not faster than JAXB, it does something different - it is needed to create textual XML after JAXB has generated the correct XML events to tell StAX what the XML should look like.

Use the following method on `javax.xml.bind.Marshaller` to send your JAXB objects to StAX:

```
/**
 * Marshal the content tree rooted at <tt>jaxbElement</tt> into a
 * {@link javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter}.
 *
 * @param jaxbElement
 *      The content tree to be marshalled.
 * @param writer
 *      XML will be sent to this writer.
 *
 * [...]
 * @since JAXB 2.0
 */
public void marshal( Object jaxbElement, javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter writer )
    throws JAXBException;
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to marshal java object by StAX automatically (without using Cursor API or Iterator API)?

Comment: No, StAX works at a different level of abstraction. For StAX, your data model already needs to work in terms of the things that you find in an XML file - an element, and attribute, a text node, etc. Java *objects* in general, unless that directly represent XML, need to be mapped using some tool, and that is not within the scope of the StAX API.